# jQuery Loads in Chrome but Not Firefox, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, firefox, google-chrome

I'm using Django and I have an HTML file, with this line in the `head` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
```

This works fine in Chrome, but it seems to have no effect in Firefox 3.6.18. (When I type in `$` or `jQuery` in the Firefox console, I get an error, whereas Chrome just shows it correctly.) The rest of my scripts can't load because of this.

I tried `strace`, and it seems like the file *is*, in fact, loaded.

What could be causing this?

---

#### More info:

I can't post a lot of the HTML, but some relevant parts:

My HTML file (Django templates):

```
{% extends "my_base.html" %}
{% load stuff %}
{% block head %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/jquery_listbox/js/jquery-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/jquery_listbox/js/ui.core-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/jquery_listbox/js/ui.dropdownchecklist-min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/jquery_listbox/css/ui.dropdownchecklist.css" />
{% endblock %}
```

`my_base.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css"/>
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

Comment: *with this line in the `meta` tag*? Really? Did you mean `head`?

Comment: What do you see in the Firebug Net and Script tabs?

Comment: @mehrdad, can you check in firebug net panel the status for jqueyr , is it throwing like permission denied or 404

Comment: @Felix: Oops, yes, I did, my bad. >__<

Comment: @SLaks, @kobe: I see 13ms in the Net tab for my jQuery file, and the Script tab shows my script just fine.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by in the meta tag? Is the script tag inside a meta tag? (OK, this is already cleared!)

Comment: Adding to other recommendations - can you pull-out everything but the line loading the jquery library (no ui-core, no ui-dropdown...)?

Comment: Have you tried without the leading / (EX: media/... NOT /media/...) or try the full path to the js file.

Comment: @Michael: Tried, no difference. :(
@Shaneburgess: I don't believe that's how things work in Django...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the rest of your HTML. With Firebug installed, you can check the Net tab to make sure the jQuery file is requested and returned correctly in Firefox. Or replace the `src` with [Google's hosted jQuery](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery) which is `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js` - if that works then you know it's a location problem, not a code problem.

Comment: Replacing the `src` made no difference. :(

Comment: It must be a problem elsewhere in the HTML that is preventing it from loading. Are there unclosed quotes, comments, etc before the `<script>` tag? We'll need to see the full HTML to help further I think.

Comment: I posted some more, but I can't post too much, unfortunately. If there's a specific part you still need that I haven't posted, let me know and I'll try my best to post it.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd clear the browser cache. Secondly I'd change that local js file to always pull from the Google CDN

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I see no reason to force jquery to always come from Google. Especially if the site is on SSL and needs its resources to be local.

Comment: he could load from https too at (https://)ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js or remove the protocol completely as //ajax.google..... Serving the js from the CDN allows for parallel downloads which is faster for the user, and in this case it would create a control on the file which would allow him to isolate his issue by removing one variable.